# Problem sending multiple strings one by one using sockets 

Tags: c, sockets, read-write

I am new to socket programming. Need to send multiple strings one-by-one to server and collect the resulting string.

Now the problem is that using send/write function in client, all the strings are read in one go from server.

```
//client.c
sendString(serversocket,"str1"); 

sendString(serversocket,"str2"); 

sendString(serversocket,"str3"); 

//server.c

char *buff=readstring(clientsocket);

printf("%s",buff) ;//output : str1str2str2
```

Need to get `str1`, `str2` and `str3`...

I need to make it as receive one after another. How can I do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TCP socket is a **byte stream** - You will have to split up the data on the receiving end.

For strings, you can do this in e.g. one of these two ways:

Client:

- send an integer length
- send the string data

Server:

- read an integer length
- read this amount of bytes into a string

Or, you can use 0-termination:

Client:

- send a string followed by a 0 byte

Server:

- Read as much as possible, scan for 0 byte, extract string

You will have to handle both of these two cases on the server end:

- Server receives 1 byte for each call to `recv()`
- Server receives all data in a single call to `recv()`

Comment: Thanks Erik.....I implemented this and this worked fine...Learned need to handle above two cases you mentioned ...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using TCP here. In which case anything sent to the socket is treated as a stream. So you'll have to add separators into the stream in order to split the strings. You could send a newline after each string and then parse the input to split the lines again.

Answer (score 0):

Since TCP is a byte stream you need to delimit your pieces of data, i.e. your logical packets.  In this case a newline character '\n' may be the most obvious choice, or you could use the null charater, '\0'.

```
//client.c
sendString(serversocket,"str1\n"); 

sendString(serversocket,"str2\n"); 

sendString(serversocket,"str3\n");
```

You could then use something like [strtok](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtok.3.html) to chop up the input data into it's component logical packets.